# nginx: 'location' as an alias for 'server'?

Tags: linux, nginx

I have nginx set up with several servers in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

However, I want to convert my setup to one domain ***myserver.com*** , so typing in a browser

```
lalala.com
```

will no longer get me to the appropriate ***/usr/share/webapps/lalala*** subfolder.

Therefore, I want to create some kind of bind (if possible) so that if I type

```
myserver.com/lalala
```

it will redirect me to ***/usr/share/webapps*** while still applying all the configuration from 
***/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/lalala***

Here are my conf files:

[nginx.conf](http://pastebin.com/aXZmhq2d)

[server example one - ownCloud](http://pastebin.com/hfXLRS2r)

Comment: We cannot help you without seeing your complete configuration.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen My apologies. Configs attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by deleting the `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` stanza from your `nginx.conf` file since that triggers the now unwanted behavior of including `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` content at `http` level.

Now you could use some locations such as:

```
server {
    root /usr/chare/webapps; # Or even move it to the upper level 'http'?

    location /lalala {
        include /etc/nginx/sites-available/lalala.conf
    }
}
```

You could then use regex locations to automate parsing the location string to grab the corresponding (existing?) file in the include directory.

Pay attention to something very important though: Traditionally, the content of the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`-like directories are `server` blocks, making nginx configuration granular. Ensure their content suits inclusion in a `location` block (trying to include a `server` in a `location` obviously won't work).

Also pay attention to the scope of directives you include there, since not all of them might be used inside `location`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is getting me a bit closer to solution. However, I need things like owncloud in those main http server subfolders, and they use things that are indeed not allowed within locations, for example:
** nginx: [emerg] "ssl_certificate" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/locs-enabled/owncloud.conf:4**
Is there some way to get around it?

Comment: Well... emulating `server` in `location` is the root of all sorts of monstruosities. I gave a reply hoping you would notice its (lack of) point.
Serving several Web hosts per machine is the whole point of the Domain Name System... ie several servers listening on different domains.
A location is simply not a server, just like a square is not a circle. I dunno what to say more than that.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, Bernard. Makes perfect sense.